# Save checkbox choice

Tags: javascript

Need to know how can I save checkbox choice, in my example I have a website with a checkbox to enable or disable dark mode. My question is how can I save the choice so the dark mode is for example enabled or disabled when I open new page of my website or even when I exit browser and come back again

Comment: You can use `localStorage` for such things (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: can you clarify what javascript libriary or framework are you working with.
because you can use cookies, chache, or redux
there are a lot of options depending on your project

Comment: @Moussaabmma Using only HTML,CSS, Javascript(jquery), I don't have my own back end because I am using data from public api

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Get the checkbox
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  

  // If the checkbox is checked, display the output text
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    window.alert("Checked")
  } else {
    window.alert("Unchecked")
  }
}
```

```html
Checkbox: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">
```

You can change the alert part with the varibale you want to associate the checkbox with:
exp darkMode = true
you can than add this variable to local story using

```
localStorage.setItem('darkMode', darkMode)
```

Comment: he want to save the state checkbox checked or not even after he close the browser
so you should add local storage or cookies or chache in your answer